# API or code to draw BPMN 2.0 processes programmatically + C#

Tags: bpmn, flowchart, use-case-diagram

Can any one suggest a solution for drawing process flow diagrams in BPMN 2.0 , flow charts, use case diagrams programmatically. 
 We are planning to read the input from an excel file. If getting some ideas we can change the input template as well.

Comment: See also [Wikipedia: Comparison of Business Process Modeling Notation tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Business_Process_Modeling_Notation_tools)

Comment: I think all those tools allow the user to manually create diagrams. I need to generate the diagrams programatically

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use the [BPMN Sketch Miner](https://design.inf.usi.ch/bpmn-sketch-miner), which can generate BPMN in XML/SVG/PNG formats starting from textual descriptions of the diagram as input.

Answer (score 0):

For simplistic BPMN diagrams, which mainly consist of a large collection of sequential acticities/ tasks, with a few gateways, using [Zeebe's YAML workflows](https://docs.zeebe.io/yaml-workflows/index.html) might be an alternative to defining a custom Excel format.

> Creating a YAML workflow can be done with a regular text editor and does not require a graphical modelling tool. It is inspired by imperative programming concepts and aims to be easily understandable by programmers. Internally, Zeebe transforms a deployed YAML file to BPMN.